# check all checkbox in react table

Tags: json, reactjs, checkbox, jsx

Hello guys I'm new to react and I was tryin to udnerstand how could I add a " toggle all " in this little app.

***Main task***

given a json value i've to display this value in the checkbox of the table. After i want to  implement a " check all " function, that helps me to check all the checkboxs.

***Problem***

I don't know how to override the given json value

***Code***

```
import React from 'react';
import {getJson} from './getJson';

class TableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        checked: false,
        rows:[],
        json: []
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          json: getJson(),
        }
      })
    }

    checkboxHandler() {

      }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.json.map((obj, i) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={obj.id}>
                    {obj.items.map((data, i) => {
                        return( 
                            <td key={data.id}> 
                                <p>{data.label}</p>
                                    <input 
                                        type="checkbox" 
                                        checked={data.value}
                                        onChange={this.checkboxHandler} 
                                    />
                            </td>
                        )
                    })}
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default TableComponent;
```

i already saw these posts:

1. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371273/react-checkbox-select-all)
2. [Second stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641541/react-input-checkbox-select-all-component)

***Json Info***

```
[{
            "id": "123",
            "items": [
              { "id": "231", label: "first", value: false },
              { "id": "4321", label: "second", value: true },
            ]
              }
          ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `map` all your objects in your `json` array and all the items in their `items` array and create copies of the arrays and objects where the `value` is set to `true`.

**Example**

```js
function getJson() {
  return [
    {
      id: "123",
      items: [
        { id: "231", label: "first", value: false },
        { id: "4321", label: "second", value: true },
        { id: "1337", label: "third", value: false }
      ]
    }
  ];
}

class TableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: false,
    rows: [],
    json: getJson()
  };

  checkboxHandler() {}

  checkAll = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const json = prevState.json.map(obj => ({
        ...obj,
        items: obj.items.map(item => ({
          ...item,
          value: true
        }))
      }));

      return { json };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.json.map((obj, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={obj.id}>
                  {obj.items.map((data, j) => {
                    return (
                      <td key={data.id}>
                        <p>{data.label}</p>
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          checked={data.value}
                          onChange={this.checkboxHandler}
                        />
                      </td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button onClick={this.checkAll}>Check all</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TableComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry if i ask another question ,but i'm not sure if it's worth open another topic. But if i want to check\uncheck ?

Comment: @Legeo You could e.g. use your `checked` property in state and use that to set all the `value`s to `true`/`false` and toggle the `checked` value as well in `checkAll`. Or you could first check if any `value` is `false`, and then set them all to `true`, else to `false`. You can open a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I prefer to spend some times to get it before speak again. 
Really thank you for everything!